# Rails s and bundle install error with pg gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails on my MacBook Pro running Yosemite 10.10 for my school program. I have installed everything successfully but now when I run rails s I get this error. I have tried to continue with bundle install to solve the issue but as you can see it does not work. What is going on here? I proceeded to try with sudo but it failed as well.

```
▶ rails s
Could not find pg-0.18.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

~/code/Bloccit  master ✔                                                                                                                                              2d  ⍉
▶ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.4.2
Using CFPropertyList 2.3.1
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.6.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Using rack 1.6.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Using globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.1
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using autoprefixer-rails 5.1.9
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using better_errors 2.1.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using sass 3.4.13
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using byebug 4.0.5
Using carrierwave 0.10.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 2.1.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.4.1
Using excon 0.45.3
Using faker 1.4.3
Using figaro 1.1.0
Using fission 0.5.0
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using net-ssh 2.9.2
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using fog-core 1.30.0
Using fog-xml 0.1.2
Using fog-atmos 0.1.0
Using multi_json 1.11.0
Using fog-json 1.0.1
Using ipaddress 0.8.0
Using fog-aws 0.1.2
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Using fog-brightbox 0.7.1
Using fog-ecloud 0.1.1
Using fog-local 0.2.1
Using fog-powerdns 0.1.1
Using fog-profitbricks 0.0.2
Using fog-radosgw 0.0.4
Using fog-riakcs 0.1.0
Using fog-sakuracloud 1.0.1
Using fog-serverlove 0.1.2
Using fog-softlayer 0.4.5
Using fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
Using fog-terremark 0.1.0
Using fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
Using fog-voxel 0.1.0
Using fog 1.29.0
Using jbuilder 2.2.13
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using mini_magick 4.2.3

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/.gemtest
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.

~/code/Bloccit  master ✔                                                                                                                                              2d  ⍉
▶ gem install pg -v '0.18.1'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/.gemtest
```

Edit: Updated with gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use will_paginate
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'

# Use Fog
gem 'fog'

# Use CarrierWave and MiniMagick
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

# Use Redcarpet
gem 'redcarpet'

# Use Pundit
gem 'pundit'

# Use Figaro
gem 'figaro'

# Use Devise
gem 'devise'

# Use Bootstrap-Sass Gem
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Use pry-rails
gem 'pry-rails'

# Faker gem
gem 'faker'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Did you see this error? "Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/.gemtest" You have a permissions issue. Who owns that directory? Your current login or some other (maybe root) account?

Comment: can you post your gemfile codes?

Comment: Gemfile added. I own the directory @MarsAtomic. I tried with Sudo and it still does not work.

Comment: try: rails s -e development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you updated your OSX recently? Maybe you need to update your xcode/xcode tools and then reinstall postgres.

Have you installed postgres by homebrew? If yes, try to reinstall running

> brew uninstall postgresql

and then

> brew install postgresql

Then, try again to run "bundle install".

Comment: I believe this worked. Everything has installed. Although my rails server shuts off immediately due to another issue now ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Add 'pg' gem into your gemfile instead installing it manually in your terminal and run 'bundle install'. 
Add this in your gemfile: 
`gem 'pg'

Comment: pg is in the Gemfile, thats where the bundle install fails

Comment: try to run this first 'bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config' before running the 'bundle install'.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less heavy handed version of penner's answer, I had the same problem and after some digging discovered that the `pg-0.18.1` directory in `lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/` was owned by root (probably due to a mistaken use of `sudo` as he notes). I `rm -rf`ed that directory (and an `extensions` one that failed the install after the `gems` one was cleaned up) and after that the install worked.

Short answer: `ls -la` your way down through that long path the error gives you, and when you find any directories owned by root, get rid of them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `-ls`, `-la` part? And how does one find directories "owned by root"? And how does one get rid of such directories? I've been struggling with `pg` gem and finally concluded the inconsistent installations were the issue, but have no clue how to fix them (esp. when I used to think global (root, in my mind) installation was the way to go.

Comment: Taking the OP's example of `/Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/.gemtest` from his error message, you would cd down into `/Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems` and do `ls -la` which lists all subdirectories and their owners. You would find that `pg-0.18.1` is owned by root, so you would `sudo rm -rf pg-0.18.1` then try the installation again. If it fails again, the directory it flags as the problem should be different, so cd down into that one, rinse and repeat the above until the installation works.

Answer (score 0):

Might be heavy handed

```
chown -R jonathanmusso:staff /Users/jonathanmusso/.rvm
```

If you've used sudo with rvm you might have broken the install. Try updating rvm.